# Need help in Python Django for fetch the records from DB which will expire in 30 days

Tags: python, django, django-views

**I wrote an application where there is a requirment to display only those records which will expire is next 30 day.**

models.py

```
class SarnarLogs(models.Model):
request_type_choice = (
    ('NAR', 'NAR'),
)
source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
expiry_date = models.DateField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.source
```

Views.py

```
@login_required(login_url=('/login'))
def expiry_requests(request):
Thirty_day = end_date = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=30)
posts = SarnarLogs.expiry_date.filter(expiry_date = Thirty_day)

context = {"console_data": posts, "user":request.user.full_name}
return render(request, 'expiry_requests.html', context=context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range):

```
posts = SarnarLogs.expiry_date.filter(expiry_date__range = (datetime.now().date(), Thirty_day))
```

Comment: Works like a butter  thanks @ruddra